# Is there a way in Gnome's file browser widget to 1) search for internal strings and 2) repeatedly search?

Tags: gnome

In Gnome's file browser widget, it's possible to search for files by simply beginning to type.

Problems:

1) This only searches the beginning of filenames. For instance, in the screenshot below, I began my search for 'gnome-' which shows a file beginning with those characters. Is there any way to force the search to also look for files where 'gnome-' appears in the middle of the filename?

2) It only provides the first matching file. Is there any way to perform a 'Find Next' (F3 usually) to continue showing me other results (beginning) with those characters. I would like to be able to press a keyboard shortcut and have it highlight the next matching file.

[image: Gnome file browser widget]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The default compare function in GTK+ list/tree views only supports matching by prefix. (Programs can specify alternate functions for lists/trees used in their own windows, but they cannot modify the GTK+ file browser window.)
2. Use <kbd>↑ Up</kbd> and <kbd>↓ Down</kbd> arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for 1., you can use Tracker (the search tool is called "needle" those days). It doesn't perfectly answer your question as it is a standalone tool but is very handy.